# Orações idênticas, classificações diferentes?

Tags: conjunções, orações-subordinadas

> (1) Ele estudou muito, por isso foi aprovado.
>
> (2) Ele estudou muito, de modo que foi aprovado.

Por que a oração "foi aprovado" é classificada como coordenada em (1) e subordinada em (2), sendo que a primeira oração de ambas as frases são idênticas e "de modo que" é sinônimo de "por isso"?

Sei que "de modo que" é uma conjunção subordinativa e, assim, uma resposta possível seria que a classificação da oração que se lhe segue como subordinada decorre da presença dessa conjunção. Contudo, esse me parece um raciocínio circular, uma vez que a definição de conjunção subordinativa é justamente aquela que introduz uma oração dependente, subordinada. Portanto, gostaria de uma resposta que levasse em consideração as definições de oração subordinada/coorndeada e de conjunção subordinativa/coordenativa. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

**A oração coordenada caracteriza duas orações sintaticamente independentes.** [veja abaixo.]

1) Ele estudou muito|| por isso foi aprovado.

**Ele estudou muito.** e "Por isso foi aprovado". são independentes uma da outra. Ou sejam, poderiam ser independentes uma da outra. Isto é, são frase completas em si.

2) Ele estudou muito, de modo que foi aprovado.

**de  modo que** introduz uma proposição subordinada, o resultado de : estudar muito.

"De modo que foi aprovado" é um consequencia ou resultada da primeira proposição e também não é sintaticamente independente. Não constitui uma frase completa.

[oração coordenada](https://mundoeducacao.bol.uol.com.br/gramatica/oracao-coordenada.htm)

Comment: Entendo, mas não deveríamos desconsiderar a presença da conjunção na hora de avaliar se as orações são independentes? Por exemplo, na oração coordenada "Vou embora para casa, que estou cansada de esperar", se fôssemos considerar a segunda oração como "Que estou cansada de esperar", seríamos levados a concluir que se trata de uma oração subordinada, visto que essa frase não possui sentido completo, mas apenas expressa a explicação da primeira oração. Porém, retirando a conjunção coordenativa, ficaríamos com duas orações independentes, o que estaria conforme a definição de oração coordenada.

Comment: @Sasaki "Vou embora para casa ***[por]que*** estou cansada de esperar".  Sem virgula. É uma  oração subordinada. Só pode ser. Ele estudou muito [e] por isso foi aprovado. Também sem virgula. E é um coordenada.